# Format time series data and create grouped barplot

Tags: r, time, matrix, dataframe, bar-chart

ok, so I'm addressing this question in a new way. I want to create a grouped barplot which shows precipitation amounts at three locations for every day. My data is stored as a .csv file. Here it is:

```
date    strick  huetten hornberg
31.01.2013  18.15   81.25   100
01.02.2013  12.7    11.75   NA
02.02.2013  59.7    61.25   NA
03.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
04.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
05.02.2013  45.25   31.3    NA
06.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
07.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
08.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
09.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
10.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
11.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
12.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
13.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
14.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
15.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
16.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
17.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
18.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
19.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
20.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
21.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
22.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
23.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
24.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
25.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
26.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
27.02.2013  NA  NA  NA
28.02.2013  55.6    NA  NA
01.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
02.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
03.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
04.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
05.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
06.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
07.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
08.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
09.03.2013  7.95    NA  NA
10.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
11.03.2013  9.65    76.2    NA
12.03.2013  1.65    3.35    NA
13.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
14.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
15.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
16.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
17.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
18.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
19.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
20.03.2013  30.2    NA  NA
21.03.2013  12.05   NA  NA
22.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
23.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
24.03.2013  2.15    NA  NA
25.03.2013  0.25    NA  NA
26.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
27.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
28.03.2013  11.4    NA  NA
29.03.2013  NA  NA  NA
30.03.2013  12.25   NA  NA
31.03.2013  6   NA  NA
01.04.2013  5.6 NA  NA
02.04.2013  NA  NA  NA
03.04.2013  NA  NA  NA
04.04.2013  NA  NA  NA
05.04.2013  NA  NA  NA
06.04.2013  NA  NA  NA
07.04.2013  NA  NA  NA
08.04.2013  NA  78.25   NA
09.04.2013  2.9 NA  NA
10.04.2013  15.6    14.25   NA
11.04.2013  11.55   11.15   NA
12.04.2013  34.8    34.75   NA
13.04.2013  9.65    11.1    NA
```

How can I create the matrix/table which I need for a grouped barplot and how can I make the x axis of the bar plot look exactly like this (I have the same time series as on the figure):
[image]

the code for this example figure is:

```
setwd("path")
rb=read.csv("mean_alllocations1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
rb$DATE<-as.POSIXct(rb$DATE, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
pdf("air_temp_mean_all_locations.pdf", width=12,height=6)
a=c("31.01.2013","07.02.2013", "14.02.2013", "21.02.2013", "28.02.2013", "07.03.2013", "14.03.2013", "21.03.2013", "28.03.2013","04.04.2013", "11.04.2013")
a<-as.POSIXct(a, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
b=c("31.01.2013","01.02.2013","02.02.2013","03.02.2013","04.02.2013","05.02.2013","06.02.2013","07.02.2013","08.02.2013","09.02.2013","10.02.2013","11.02.2013","12.02.2013","13.02.2013","14.02.2013","15.02.2013","16.02.2013","17.02.2013","18.02.2013","19.02.2013","20.02.2013","21.02.2013","22.02.2013","23.02.2013","24.02.2013","25.02.2013","26.02.2013","27.02.2013","28.02.2013","01.03.2013","02.03.2013","03.03.2013","04.03.2013","05.03.2013","06.03.2013","07.03.2013","08.03.2013","09.03.2013","10.03.2013","11.03.2013","12.03.2013","13.03.2013","14.03.2013","15.03.2013","16.03.2013","17.03.2013","18.03.2013","19.03.2013","20.03.2013","21.03.2013","22.03.2013","23.03.2013","24.03.2013","25.03.2013","26.03.2013","27.03.2013","28.03.2013","29.03.2013","30.03.2013","31.03.2013","01.04.2013","02.04.2013","03.04.2013","04.04.2013","05.04.2013","06.04.2013","07.04.2013","08.04.2013","09.04.2013","10.04.2013","11.04.2013","12.04.2013","13.04.2013")
b<-as.POSIXct(b, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
par(mar=c(5,4,0.5,0.5))
plot(rb$DATE, rb$RBGL830_TEMP_MIN, ylim=c(-10,10), xlim = c(min(rb$DATE),max(rb$DATE)), axes = TRUE, "l", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", col="olivedrab2", lwd=1.0, xlab="", ylab="",xaxs="i", panel.first= abline(h = c(-10, -5, 0, 5, 10), col = "grey", lty = 3))
axis(2, c(-10, 10, c(-10, -5, 0, 5, 10)), las=1)
axis(1, at=a, labels=FALSE)
axis(1, at=b, labels=FALSE, tck=-0.01)
text(a, par("usr")[3] - 0.8, srt = 45, adj = 1,labels =format(a, format ="%d.%m.%Y"), xpd = TRUE) 
mtext(1, text="Time", line=4)
mtext(2, text="Mean Daily Air Temperature [°C]", line=2.5)
abline(h = c(20, 15, 10, 5, 0, -5, -10, -15, -20), col = "grey", lty = 2)
lines(rb$DATE, rb$SBGL836_TEMP_MIN, "l", col="limegreen", lwd=1.0)
lines(rb$DATE, rb$SBGL989_TEMP_MIN, "l", col="darkgreen", lwd=1.0)
lines(rb$DATE, rb$SBBF872_TEMP_MIN, "l", col="sienna3", lwd=1.0)
lines(rb$DATE, rb$SBF993_TEMP_MIN, "l", col="sienna4", lwd=1.0)
points(rb$DATE, rb$RBGL830_TEMP_MIN, pch=20, col="olivedrab2")
points(rb$DATE, rb$SBGL836_TEMP_MIN, pch=20, col="limegreen")
points(rb$DATE, rb$SBGL989_TEMP_MIN, pch=20, col="darkgreen")
points(rb$DATE, rb$SBBF872_TEMP_MIN, pch=18, col="sienna3")
points(rb$DATE, rb$SBF993_TEMP_MIN, pch=18, col="sienna4")
legend("bottomright", c("[4] SB Grassland 989 m","[5] SB Grassland 836 m","[8] RB Grassland 830 m","[6] SB Forest 993 m","[7] SBB Forest 872 m"), bty="n" , lwd=c(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0), pch=c(20,20,20,18,18), col=c("darkgreen","limegreen","olivedrab2","sienna4","sienna3"))
dev.off()
```

I created a matrix manually and created a barplot from it, but there's a mistake (there shouldn't be values for "hornberg"->see data) and with this approach I don't know how have the x axis as a time series.

```
a<-c(18.15,12.7,59.7,NA,NA,45.25,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,55.6,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,7.95,NA,9.65,1.65,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,30.2,12.05,NA,NA,2.15,0.25,NA,NA,11.4,NA,12.25,6,5.6,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2.9,15.6,11.55,34.8,9.65)
b<-c(81.25,11.75,61.25,NA,NA,31.3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,76.2,3.35,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,78.25,NA,14.25,11.15,34.75,11.1)
c<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
mymatrix<-matrix(c(a,b,c),73)
colnames(mymatrix)<-c("huetten","strick","hornberg")
rownames(mymatrix)<-c("31.01.2013","01.02.2013","02.02.2013","03.02.2013","04.02.2013","05.02.2013","06.02.2013","07.02.2013","08.02.2013","09.02.2013","10.02.2013","11.02.2013","12.02.2013","13.02.2013","14.02.2013","15.02.2013","16.02.2013","17.02.2013","18.02.2013","19.02.2013","20.02.2013","21.02.2013","22.02.2013","23.02.2013","24.02.2013","25.02.2013","26.02.2013","27.02.2013","28.02.2013","01.03.2013","02.03.2013","03.03.2013","04.03.2013","05.03.2013","06.03.2013","07.03.2013","08.03.2013","09.03.2013","10.03.2013","11.03.2013","12.03.2013","13.03.2013","14.03.2013","15.03.2013","16.03.2013","17.03.2013","18.03.2013","19.03.2013","20.03.2013","21.03.2013","22.03.2013","23.03.2013","24.03.2013","25.03.2013","26.03.2013","27.03.2013","28.03.2013","29.03.2013","30.03.2013","31.03.2013","01.04.2013","02.04.2013","03.04.2013","04.04.2013","05.04.2013","06.04.2013","07.04.2013","08.04.2013","09.04.2013","10.04.2013","11.04.2013","12.04.2013","13.04.2013")
pdf("test.pdf",width=12,height=6)
barplot(mymatrix, beside=TRUE, ylim=c(0,100), col=c("blue","red","black"),las=1)
mtext(2, text="Precipitation [mm/d]", line=2.7)
box()
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but a `matrix` in R has to be all one type.  So you should only use your numeric data in this case (I think).  You can set `rownames` of a matrix to anything you'd like (almost)... but I don't know if that is your question.  Can you supply some clue as to what you're trying to accomplish in a broader sense?

Comment: In the meantime!? So we are supposed to spend our time helping you with an answer while you are googling? You should do your [search and research **before** asking your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @Justin: I want to eventually create a grouped barplot and from my understanding you need a matrix do do so. Since I have a lot of values I would like to be able to "convert" my data.frame from the .csv file to a matrix. For my barplot I want Values on the y axis and the dates on the x axis giving me a grouped barplot with three bars per date. I don't want to have to create the matrix manually and I believe there should be a way that you can assign a date to every set of values.

Comment: @Henrik: I have been doing research and trying to figure it out. I'm an absolute beginner with r as well as with programing language so it takes a lot of time to figure things out plus I have some time pressure. If I were able to solve it on my own I wouldn't poste a question, in the meantime I might as well do more research rather than do nothing about it.

Comment: @samjam, I fully understand the struggle as a beginner. I highly recommend you to read [introductory texts](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info), work through examples found on SO and e.g. [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/), search SO properly for your "keywords", e.g. [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+grouped+barplot) or [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+dates+on+x+axis). Finally, I think in many (most?) cases you are just fine keeping your data in a data frame when plotting. If you at some point want to use `ggplot`, your data _have_ to be in a data frame.

Comment: @Henrik: Thanks for your advice! I'm looking through your links right now:)

Comment: @Henrik: i'm not getting any further with this...tried creating matrix manually which worked but I don't know to get from the matrix to the barplot. I'm having trouble with the adding the dates to the xaxis...

Comment: @samjam, as I tried to say before, you don't have to convert your data to a matrix. Use `read.table` and work with the resulting data frame. Please study my suggested searches on SO carefully, and work through simple examples step by step. I can also recommend [this tutorial](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/).

Comment: @Hernrik: ok, I thought read table wouldn't work with .csv but I'll give it another shot. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have read your file to R, using `read.table`, there is no need to convert the resulting data frame to a matrix. In my example, I assume your data frame is called 'df'.

```
# load necessary packages
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# melt data from wide to long format
df2 <- melt(data = df, id.vars = "date", variable.name = "Location", value.name = "Precipitation")
str(df2)

# change 'date' to class Date
df2$date <- as.Date(df2$date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")

# reorder and rename levels of Location
df2$Location <- factor(df2$Location,
                       levels = c("hornberg", "huetten", "strick"),
                       labels = c("Hornberg", "Huetten", "Strick"))

# plot
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = date, y = Precipitation, fill = Location)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_date(
    breaks = seq(from = as.Date("2013-01-31"), to = as.Date("2013-04-13"), by = "week"),
    labels = date_format("%d.%m.%Y")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 105)) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Precipitation (mm/d)") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(linetype = "longdash"))
```

[image]

Comment: hi henrik, thank you so much for your help!!! This is what I was trying to create! Only two more questions, than I'll be satisfied with the plot: 1) How can I change the date format form "year-month-day" to "day.month.year". I tried this: ...scale_x_date(breaks = seq(from = as.Date("31.01.2013"), format= "%d.%m.%Y", to = as.Date("13.04.2013"), format= "%d.%m.%Y", by = "week"))... ->inserting the format to the seq.column but i get this error:

Comment: Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format. 2) how come I have an y-offset in my plot and you don't? I want no y and x axis offset. I tried "+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 90))" but nothing happened. See awnser for my current plot

Comment: Thanks again for your effort, you've been extremly helpful! I marked your answer as suitable and upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
structure(as.matrix(x[,-1]), dimnames=list(as.character(x[,1]),names(x)[-1]))
```

Result:

```
           London New_York Moscow
31.01.2013    400      750    390
01.02.2013    350      700    300
02.02.2013    330      730    250
03.02.3013    300      650    250
```

OBS: using input:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="
Date         London   New_York   Moscow    
31.01.2013   400      750        390
01.02.2013   350      700        300
02.02.2013   330      730        250
03.02.3013   300      650        250
")
```